# How to Upgrade to GTK+ 3.14 or higher on Linux 17.2

Tags: linux, gtk, meld

I want to install meld on my linux but I'm getting this error `Meld requires GTK+ 3.14 or higher.` when I'm running meld on my terminal

Comment: What distribution are you using? What version of that distribution? Kernel version is rarely useful here. Also how did you install meld without the right version of GTK+?!

Comment: distribution of what? and I installed meld by cloning it

Comment: Distribution of Linux. Ah, so you did not build it yet; that makes more sense.

Comment: Being that the version number is 17.2, I assume the distro is Linux Mint. @AnkitKumar, you might want to learn more about Linux if you plan to use it much.

Answer (score 1):

Uninstall the version from Github that You have installed and install the one from Distribution Repository (I am assuming that You are on Linux Mint 17.2) :

`$ sudo aptitude install meld`

This will install the proper meld for Your version of GTK.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint is not bleeding-edge enough for 3.14. They are still back on 3.10.8, so you can either backport/build it (not recommended) or find a different distro, like Debian or Ubuntu, for example.

Comment: Manual building is fine using jhbuild, which is also made by the GNOME developers. It will use a custom prefix for everything, so everything stays separate.

Comment: That may be true but I still would recommend switching distros for two reasons: 1) I vastly prefer binary packages and 2) Linux Mint is not exactly a development distro.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently.  Solved it by installing `PyGObject`:

```
pip install pygobject
```